# Leer desde un archivo y asignar a array [][] en Java

Tags: java, matrices

¿Cómo leer un archivo *txt* con una matriz de *8x11* que tiene varios `char` y meterlo en un `char [][]`?

El *txt* puede tener esta forma:

```
%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%
%,%,%,h,o,l,a,%,%,%,%
%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%
%,%,%,m,u,n,d,o,%,%,%
%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%
%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%
%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%
```

¿Cómo se hace para leer el *txt* anterior desde Java y meterlo tal cual con sus filas y columnas en un `char [][]`? No en un vector `[]`, sino en una matriz, respetando las filas y las columnas.

Comment: Hola Keka, gracias por tu pregunta. Por favor, no te olvides compartir el codigo de lo que has hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.*

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se trata de una tarea escolar sin aportar código o trabajo realizado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria usando la clase BufferedReader

**Obtiene la instancia para poder leer el archivo**

```
 public BufferedReader getBuffered(String link){

    FileReader lector  = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
         File Arch=new File(link);
        if(!Arch.exists()){
           System.out.println("No existe el archivo");
        }else{
           lector = new FileReader(link);
           br = new BufferedReader(lector);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return br;
}
```

**hacemos la lectura de archivo linea por linea y lo guardamos en el arreglo de caracteres**

```
 public void readTxt(){
    try {
        //ruta de tu archivo
        String ruta = "archivo.txt"
        BufferedReader br = getBuffered(ruta);
        //leemos la primera linea
        String linea =  br.readLine();
        //creamos la matriz vacia
        char[][] = new char[8][11];
        //contador
        int contador = 0;
        while(linea != null){
            String[] values = linea.split(",");
            //recorremos el arrar de string
            for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
                //se obtiene el primer caracter de el arreglo de strings
                char[contador][i] = values[i].charAt(0);
            }
            contador++;
            linea = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mm no buscaba el código entero, solo alguna orientación sobre que clase o método usar ^^ pero gracias. En cuanto a lo que dicen arriba los compañeros de que debía aportar el código hecho hasta ahora, tenía el de leer y meter en un vector, no en una matriz. Y no es una tarea escolar tengo 43 años y me estoy iniciando en el mundillo de la programación jeje. Un saludo