# ¿Cómo leer el contenido de un archivo, obteniendo su contenido como int en una matriz? (Java)

Tags: java, array, archivo, matrices, split

Buen día. Quiero leer un archivo `.txt`, cuyo contenido es una matriz que solo está separada en filas y columnas por comas y saltos de línea, tal y como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Estructura del contenido del .txt]

Pero me gustaría que al momento de leer el archivo, su contenido se almacenara en una matriz de 4x4, tal y como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Estructura de la matriz ya leida]

Por ahora solo consigo leer y mostrar el contenido del archivo. He estado investigando bastante y veo que con la función `split` se consigue separar el texto de manera que se le podría quitar las comas que contiene el archivo para que así solo queden los números, pero no tengo idea de cómo implementarlo en mi código de manera que se aloje en una matriz.

Lo que llevo de código es esto, y como repito solo consigo leer el contenido de la matriz. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, y de antemano gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    leerArchivo("eliminar.txt");//Ubicacion relativa del archivo
}

public static void leerArchivo(String ruta) {

    String dato;

    try {
        File archivo = new File(ruta);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(archivo);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            dato = myReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(dato);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Éste sería el código que he pensado:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String cadena;
        FileReader f = new FileReader("lib/eliminar.txt");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        Integer i = 0;
        String temp[] = new String[4];
        Integer numbers[] = new Integer[4];
        Integer res[][] = new Integer[4][4];

        while ((cadena = b.readLine()) != null) {

            temp = cadena.split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                numbers[j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[j]);
                res[i][j] = numbers[j];

            }
            i++;

        }

        b.close();

        for (int k = 0; k < res.length; k++) {
            for (int j2 = 0; j2 < res.length; j2++) {
                System.out.println(res[k][j2]);

            }
        }

    }
```

Fuentes para leer el fichero y agarrar cada línea:
[desde chuwiki](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Lectura_y_Escritura_de_Ficheros_en_Java#Lectura_de_un_fichero_de_texto_en_java) y [geekytheory](https://geekytheory.com/como-leer-un-fichero-en-java)

Una vez hecho eso, el procedimiento sería el siguiente:
Para cada línea del fichero (que es un `String`) tengo que quitar las comas con `.split()`. Ello me devolverá un `String[]` al que he llamado **temp**. Ahora hay que recorrer ese array y parsear uno por uno los caracteres a tipo `Integer`, para hacerlo, hay que mandar esos mismos números ya parseados a un array auxiliar con las mismas dimesiones que la línea original, esto es, el `array` **numbers**.

Por último, solo queda mandar ese array de números a su posición deseada en el array bidimensional, llamado **res**. Como hay que respetar las posiciones que pones en el ejemplo, me aseguro de ello, con una variable auxiliar que, a modo de contador, me indique en qué fila de qué columna ha de ir cada número del array auxiliar.

Para que pueda seguir avanzando posiciones, el contador se debe de incrementar con `i++`, el `BufferedReader` cerrarse y, una pequeña prueba por consola del buen funcionamiento del código.

La salida sería esta:

```java
1
2
3
1
2
4
5
4
1
5
8
9
1
4
4
3
```

Sé que queda muy feo, no tiene forma de matriz, pero es así. Ya si quieres, puedes averiguar cómo modificar la salida por la consola para que quede como pones, o bien (que lo veo incluso mejor), guardarte el array bidimensional en un archivo de texto, igual que el de entrada.

Fuentes para el resto:

- https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/multidimensional-array
- https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=233:arrays-arreglos-multidimensionales-en-java-declaracion-y-uso-ejemplos-y-ejercicios-resueltos-cu00905c&catid=58&Itemid=180
- http://www.edu4java.com/es/progbasica/progbasica9.html
- http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/clases1/arays.htm#Arrays%20multidimensionales
- [Llenar un array [] [] "bidimensional" desde un archivo de texto con elementos separados por comas y renglones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101896/llenar-un-array-bidimensional-desde-un-archivo-de-texto-con-elementos-se)
- [Leer desde un archivo y asignar a array [][] en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37407/leer-desde-un-archivo-y-asignar-a-array-en-java)

Comment: solo no entiendo porque en el arreglo de temp y de numbers los declaras con un tamaño de 4, podrías indicarme por que? gracias!

Comment: @EduardoHerrera perdona en responder, estaba liado. Pues el tamaño de ambos es 4 porque así son las dimensiones de la matriz que pasaste. Cito: >su contenido se almacenara en una matriz de 4x4

Comment: y si supongamos fuera una matriz de 3x6 como quedarían los campos? Porque he intentado y no consigo que compile

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
try {
fr = new FileReader(archivo);
br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String linea = br.readLine(); // lee la primera linea
String temp[];

while (linea != null) { // mientras hayan lineas...
    temp = linea.split(","); // separa los strings

    // ahora puedes recoger cada trozo de la lina
    // con temp[0], temp[1], temp[2] y temp[3]
            
      
    linea = br.readLine(); // siguiente linea
}
} catch...
```